# Make Wordpress subcategories use Category Template

Tags: wordpress, templates, categories

I've got a category template: category-projects.php

This category has subcategories, but they're refering to the template category.php for instructions instead of the parent category. How do I make subcategories refer to parent category templates in the cascading order of template references?

*Note, I'm talking about category level urls, not posts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way to do this is to hook into the [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Template_Actions) action in your `functions.php` file:

```
function myTemplateSelect() {
    if (is_category() && !is_feed()) {
        if (is_category(get_cat_id('projects')) || cat_is_ancestor_of(get_cat_id('projects'), get_query_var('cat'))) {
            load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-projects.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'myTemplateSelect');
```

Comment: Woooooahhhhhh! That's awesome! Is there any way to abstract it out further, and have it apply to ALL subcategories of ALL categories, rather than declaring them each literally?

Comment: TheDeadMedic's answer to your subsequent question should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119961/make-all-wordpress-categories-use-their-parent-category-template

Comment: function is amazing, really useful but...

I GOT A SIMPLE QUESTION:

- if I change the structure of permalink and make the common url mydomain.com/CATEGORY/categoryname/subcategoryname this way: mydomain.com/categoryname/subcategoryname 

how is it possible to let the function works again? Infact, if I change the permalink structure that way, template_redirect doesn't work anymore....

any idea? please help!
thank you!

Comment: this is the best way I've found so far. I've tried to make it work JUST for subcategories:

instead of if (is_category(get_cat_id('projects')) || cat_is_ancestor_of(get_cat_id('projects'), get_query_var('cat')))
I've tried using just if (cat_is_ancestor_of(get_cat_id('projects'), get_query_var('cat')))

but it does not work, any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

Richard's answer does work but it will heavily interfere with other plugins.

I found a better alternative using `add_filter` & `template_include` as the example below

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_callback' );

function my_callback( $original_template ) {
    if ( some_condition() ) {
        return SOME_PATH . '/some-custom-file.php';
    } else {
        return $original_template;
    }
}
```

Credit to https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/

Answer (score 1):

As far i know; according to wp template hierarchy, category-samplecat.php is only applies to a category with slug name "samplecat". So it's not possible to do it in this way.

But in the category.php file (that applies to every category which hasn't a special template file) you can make a conditional check if current category is a child of "project" (using this method in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114988/wordpress-get-current-category-parents) to your other question) and if so you can apply same structure of category-projects.php to it or include category-projects.php.