# Wordpress - Get Current Category Parents

Tags: wordpress, categories

In category.php, how would I test against a category having a parent category?

If the parent category is A, and the sub-category is B, and the user loads the URL for category B, I would like to be able to test if it has parent A, and run code if it does.

I've found the get_category_parents tag, but it seems to return a link list rather than an array:

```
get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ', '));
```

Even if I got the array, I'm not sure what the php function is to test against it (php noob).

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`cat_is_ancestor_of`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/cat_is_ancestor_of) function to check if a category is a child of another category. For example to check if the current category is a child of a category named 'blog':

```
cat_is_ancestor_of(get_cat_id('blog'), get_query_var('cat'))
```

Comment: While within `category.php` (or any single category-template) you can use the global var $cat to retrieve current category's ID.
So you would check `cat_is_ancestor_of( ID, $cat );`
Using IDs is generally the better aproach, since they don't change when renaming the name/slug/whatever.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to get current category's id:

```
$category_id = get_query_var('cat');
```

Then you can make a database query to see it has a parent or not:

```
$parent = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT parent FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = $category_id");
```

If it has one, $parent will contain one-level-above parent's id and naturally it's value should be greater than 0, so you can check this like below:

```
<?php if ($parent > 0 ) : ?>
// do something
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can use $parent however you want;

```
$parent_link = get_category_link( $parent );
$parent_name = get_cat_name( $parent );
// etc.
```

If you want to see that there is more high-level parent's, you can do the same things(db query) with parent's id or even write a recursive function that go to until top level. As i saw in the source code, built-in get_category_parents() function do it like that.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Check out the reference page for [`get_category_parents`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents), you are asking for links when you set the second parameter to `TRUE`.

You should be doing:

```
    get_category_parents($cat, FALSE, ', '));
```

I also recommend not using spaces as separators, since you will probably need to trim those spaces later.