# Wordpress: parent category ID given current category ID?

Tags: wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress - Get Current Category Parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114988/wordpress-get-current-category-parents)

I'm learning wordpress.

How can I get the PARENT CATEGORY ID from the CURRENT CATEGORY ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search Google and uou will flooded with answers. Check the following WordPress function and other links.

WordPress has the inbuilt function [**get category parents**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents)

Other useful Links:

1. [WORDPRESS: GET ID OF TOP-LEVEL PARENT
   CATEGORY](http://alex.leonard.ie/2011/04/20/wordpress-get-id-of-top-level-parent-category/)
2. [How to get parent category name in
   WordPress](http://corpocrat.com/2008/10/31/how-to-get-parent-category-name-in-wordpress/)
3. [Wordpress - Get Current Category
   Parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114988/wordpress-get-current-category-parents)

Comment: Thanks Libin, the third link above (exactely here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3115369/1080599) is the right way (it works for me).

Comment: You are welcome.. =) If the problem solved, then you can mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$childCat = get_category($child_category_id);
$parentCat = get_category($childCat->parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it nice and simple

All the best

Adi
www.mindmyweb.com