# Create Wordpress category template dynamically

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

I want to  create a plugin which will create a  category template dynamically  with category slug name when I am creating an sub category .

Like i have an category news.For that I have a template "category-news.php". Now I am creating a new sub category under news named 'latest news'. So for that I want to create a file pragmatically  named 'category-latest-news.php' in my theme folder and put the category-news.php template code in to it.

Comment: The purpose of this plugin is that all sub category should follow the tamplate of  parent category . What I am looking for that I have found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114934/make-wordpress-subcategories-use-category-template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php's fopen and fwrite to create a file and then insert the template name at the top of the file programmatically.

To get the parent ID of the current page:

```
$parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
$parentsid = $parents[count($parents)-1];
```

Then you can use the code from [Make Wordpress subcategories use Category Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114934/make-wordpress-subcategories-use-category-template)

```
function myTemplateSelect() {
    if (is_category() && !is_feed()) {
        if (is_category(get_cat_id('projects')) || cat_is_ancestor_of(get_cat_id('projects'), get_query_var('cat'))) {
            load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-projects.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'myTemplateSelect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use template filter

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_include', 10 );
```

and change the template as

```
function template_include($template)
{

    if(your condition here){
        $template = get_template_directory().'/your-template.php';
    }

    return $template;
}
```