# Wordpress Template for all child categories but not for parent

Tags: wordpress, templates, categories

The best way I've found in Wordpress to use the same category template for child and grand-child categories is right here on stackoverflow: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3117202/391929

BUt how to make JUST subcategories use that template and NOT the base parent category?

I've tried editing just the if line like that, from this:

```
if (is_category(get_cat_id('projects')) || cat_is_ancestor_of(get_cat_id('projects'), get_query_var('cat')))
```

to this:

```
if (is_category(get_cat_id('projects')) || cat_is_ancestor_of(get_cat_id('projects'), get_query_var('cat')))
```

But it's not working, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this in a procedural way:

1 added in theme function this snippet:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'load_category_tree_template');
function load_category_tree_template() {
        if (is_category() && !is_feed()) {
            // replace 'your-base-category-slug' with the slug of root category
            $base_tree_cat_id = get_cat_id('your-base-category-slug'); 
                // get current category id
            $catid = get_query_var('cat'); 

            if (is_category($base_tree_cat_id) || cat_is_ancestor_of($base_tree_cat_id, $catid)) {
                load_template(STYLESHEETPATH . '/category-your-base-category-slug.php');
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in category-your-root-category-slug.php file i include a different other file based on current category slug:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
if (is_category( )) {
  $cat = get_query_var('cat');
  $currentcat = get_category ($cat);
  $currentslug = $currentcat->slug;
 }
// if we are in base category we know it by the slug
if ($currentslug == 'your-base-category-slug'){
        // if we are load a file with the loop for the root category
    require_once('post-loop-caregory-tree-root.php'); 
}else{
        // otherwise we are not in the root, so show the loop for all other category in the tree
    require_once('post-loop-category-tree.php'); 
}
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I know it can be done better, but it's quite simple solution in the end.

Comment: As no other advice is coming I keep my answer as the good one, but I'm sure this can be done in a better way...