# Wordpress category-id template to work with its subcategories

Tags: wordpress

I made a custom `category-id` template and I want that THIS category's subcategories would use same template.

Is it possible? If it is, then how to do it?

Comment: this seems like something that was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114934/make-wordpress-subcategories-use-category-template

Comment: thanks man, looks like I solved it. :). I dunno how I havent found this before ;/

Comment: Glad to know, I'm pretty new to stack overflow (posting wise) and I didn't know if I should add the reference to the other post as an "answer" or a comment here.